# Applying color ramp/map to mosaic using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, mosaic, hillshade

My goal is to create a bold, colorful hillshade following [this tutorial](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/01/18/combining-colored-and-grayshade-rasters-with-high-fidelity/) from the ESRI website.
Everything works great until I try to apply a color ramp or colormap. It somehow crunches the values and all I receive is this psychedelic hillshade.

[image: lsd-map]

I tried identifying my issue with the identify tool (how original) and there I noticed that no matter where I click on my mosaic, I receive the same output.

[image: identifier view]

I must have botched up my values but don't know, when that happened. Maybe it is worth noting that I pretreated the DEM using focal statistics with a mean stat type.

EDIT:

Adding image of symbology.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty bold and colorful to me. :) As for the identify tool, Footprint means the polygon that represents the extents of a particular raster in the mosaic dataset. You want to expand the Image sub-item.

Comment: Could you also capture the Symbology tab of the mosaic and supply in your question together with min and max raster cell values?